# Why this limit of integration? ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> I have the ODE
>   \begin{align}
> u'(x)&=f(x), \qquad a<x\leq b \tag{1} \\ 
> u(a)&=u_0
> \end{align}
>   The solution is given as
>   \begin{align}
> u(x)=\int_a^x f(y) \, dy +u_0 \qquad \text{for }  a\leq x\leq b \tag{2}
> \end{align}

But why is the upper limit $x$ and not $b$? 
I mean, why is the solution not 
\begin{align}
u(x)=\int_a^b f(y) \, dy +u_0 \quad?  
\end{align}

And also, in (1) the inteval is $a<x\leq b$, but in (2) it is changed to $a\leq x \leq b$, why?

Comment: This seems like there is some confusion surrounding the fundamental theorem of calculus. If the upper limit was $b$, then the integral would have a definite fixed value i.e $u(x) = C$. If you differentiate this solution, would it be equivalent to the ODE you started with?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{du}{dx}=f(x) \quad\to\quad du=f(x)dx\quad\to\quad u(x)=\int f(x)dx$$

The integral is an indefinite integral : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IndefiniteIntegral.html

An indefinite integral means a family of definite integrals :

$$\int f(x)dx=\int_{x_0}^x f(t)dt+C$$
where $t$ is a dummy variable.

$x_0$ and $C$ are arbitrary.

The boundary condition $u(a)=u_0$ determines a particular integral among the family of integrals :

$$u(a)=u_0=\int_{x_0}^{a} f(t)dt+C \quad\to\quad C= -\int_{x_0}^{a} f(t)dt+u_0$$
Hence :
$$u(x)=\int_{x_0}^{x} f(t)dt+C=\int_{x_0}^{x} f(t)dt+\left(-\int_{x_0}^{a} f(t)dt+u_0 \right)$$
$\int_{x_0}^{x} f(t)dt-\int_{x_0}^{a} f(t)dt=\int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt$
$$u(x)=\int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt+u_0$$

Since $f(x)$ is defined on the range $a\leq x \leq b$ then $\int_{a}^{x} f(t)dt$ is defined on the same range and $u(x)$ as well.

For example : $u(b)=\int_{a}^{b} f(t)dt+u_0$

Your first question :

> But why is the upper limit $x$ and not $b$? 
>   I mean, why is the solution not 
>   \begin{align}
> u(x)=\int_a^b f(y) \, dy +u_0 \quad?  
> \end{align}

No, because this equation gives $u(b)$, not $u(x)$ as shown above.

Your second question :

> And also, in (1) the inteval is $a<x\leq b$, but in (2) it is changed to $a\leq x \leq b$, why?

Since $u(a)=u_0$ is given, $u(a)$ is determined. So, the whole range of $x$ (where $u(x)$ is determined) is $a\leq x \leq b$.